# how to assign Dictionary.items to a class object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Hi I am migrating VB6 to vb.net and planning to replace `Scripting.Dictionary` with `Dictionary(Of String, clsAnimal)`.

The below code is vb6 which uses a `Dictionary`

```
   Dim clsAni As clsAnimal '(This is a class object)
   Dim test As String
   Set clsAni = m_dicDemographics.Item(test)
```

So how can I rewrite the above in VB.Net using `Dictionary(Of String, clsAnimal)`?

Comment: Where is this integer key for your dictionary(of integer, string)? It looks like you have a class object, and a string for a key. In that case, you'd want a dictionary(of string, clsAnimal) and the syntax would be m_dicDemographics(test) = clsAni for adding, clsAni = m_dicDemographics(test) for retrieving

Comment: It all depends on what m_dicDemographics is. How do you declare it?

Comment: thanks soohoonigan. you are right, it should be dictionary(of string, clsAnimal)

Comment: @vandy, you should edit the question to make any corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete sample:

```
Public Class clsAnimal  
    ' Members go here.
End Class

Module Module1
    Dim m_dicDemographics As Dictionary(Of String, clsAnimal) = New Dictionary(Of String, clsAnimal)

Sub Main()
    m_dicDemographics.Add("Frog", New clsAnimal())
    Dim clsAni As clsAnimal = m_dicDemographics.Item("Frog")
End Sub

End Module
```